# PostgreSQL: Select a single-row x amount of times

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

A single row in a table has a column with an integer value >= 1 and must be selected however many times the column says. So if the column had '2', I'd like the select query to return the single-row 2 times.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Will there be more rows in the table that should be replicated appropriately or is it always just the one row?

Comment: Also, can you give us an indication on why you're using this approach? There might be an cleaner solution.

Comment: This is a very odd requirement, are you dealing with a legacy app that needs this format?  Though, if you have control of the select statement being passed in, can't you just use a loop in your application code instead?

Answer (score 19):

Don't know why you would want to do such a thing, but...

```
CREATE TABLE testy (a int,b text);
INSERT INTO testy VALUES (3,'test');
SELECT testy.*,generate_series(1,a) from testy;  --returns 3 rows
```

Comment: As an example, I need exactly this for generation of random samples where the integer column defines the number of samples per category.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a table that is just full of numbers, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers
(
  num INT NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT numbers_pk PRIMARY KEY (num)
);
```

and populate it with as many numbers as you need, starting from one:

```
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES(3);
...
```

Then, if you had the table "mydata" that han to repeat based on the column "repeat_count" you would query it like so:

```
SELECT mydata.*
FROM mydata
JOIN numbers
ON numbers.num <= mydata.repeat_count
WHERE ...
```

If course you need to know the maximum repeat count up front, and have your numbers table go that high.

No idea why you would want to do this thought.  Care to share?

Comment: If whoever the down-voter was reads this, care to share why? Not wanting to argue, just curious for my own edification.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a recursive query, check out the examples in
[the postgresql docs](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/queries-with.html).

something like

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(cnt, id, field2, field3) AS (
        SELECT 1, id, field2, field3
        FROM foo
      UNION ALL
        SELECT t.cnt+1, t.id, t.field2, t.field3
        FROM t, foo f
        WHERE t.id = f.id and t.cnt < f.repeat_cnt
)
SELECT id, field2, field3 FROM t;
```

Comment: Only in 8.4 which is only beta still.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is making a simple select, like this:

```
SELECT generate_series(1,{xTimes}), a.field1, a.field2 FROM my_table a;
```