# select row n times with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables. **Person**, **Group** and **PersonGroup**.
Each **Person** can be in multiple **Groups**.
In the **PersonGroup** table there's a field called *ShowCount*, which says how many times a **Person** should be shown.

Example:
Person Bill is in group StackOverflow and should be displayed 3 times so the output should be like this

```
Bill 
Bill 
Bill
```

is there a way to do this with SQL?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Two ideas: 1) join with a "numbers" table 2) [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).

Comment: Your data model sounds a little odd - why is bill in the same group three times?

Comment: He's not. if he was there would be three entries. The ShowCount says how many times his address should be printed out (or be on the report).

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472662/make-sql-select-same-row-multiple-times (the answer by @van)

Comment: Or this answer by @Evan: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988916/postgresql-select-a-single-row-x-amount-of-times

Comment: @MarkByers i tried to make it with recursion. but without success and i did it with the numbers table but i don't like the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello a numbers table can help you with solution.
You can find the function code at http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-tsql-cte-numbers-table.aspx

Here is a sample t-sql script

```
select
    pg.showcount,
    p.name,
    g.groupname
from PersonGroup pg
inner join Person p on p.personid = pg.personid
inner join Groups g on g.groupid = pg.groupid
inner join dbo.NumbersTable(1,12,1) n on pg.showcount >= n.i
```

I hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select P.name
from person P
join PersonGroup pg on pg.person_id=p.id
join master.dbo.spt_values where type='P' and number>0 and number <= pg.ShowCount
```

Answer (score 0):

so thats how we did it now:

```
WITH ShowCounter AS (SELECT 1 AS ShowCount 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ShowCount + 1
            FROM ShowCounter 
            WHERE (ShowCount + 1 <= 100))
SELECT Person.Name
FROM ShowCounter 
INNER JOIN Person ON ShowCounter.ShowCount <= Person.ShowCount
ORDER BY PersonGroup.PersonGroupID
```

this works for ShowCount <= 100